# How do I evaluate $ \displaystyle L = \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \sqrt{1 + [- \cot(x)]^{2}} ~ \mathrm{d}{x} $?

Tags: calculus, integration

I wish to calculate the arc-length of the curve
$$
y = - \ln \sin(x), \quad x \in \left[ \frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3} \right].
$$
Differentiating $ y $, I get
$$
y' = - \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)},
$$
so the desired arc-length is $ \displaystyle L = \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \sqrt{1 + [- \cot(x)]^{2}} ~ \mathrm{d}{x} $. How, then, can I proceed to evaluate this integral?

Answer (score 3):

Use $1 + \cot^2 x = \csc^2 x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$1+\cot(x)^2=\csc(x)^2$$ so you get $$\int{\csc(x)dx}=\ln\big(\csc(x)-\cot(x)\big)$$